# Adding a styled div with specific content from text input box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, append

Sorry I'm kinda a javascript noob. I'm using Jquery.

I have an input box and I want to take the text input and make a new div with the input and have the appropriate tags on it.

Specifically, take the input value and output:

Input Value  5

and clear the input box and move it down 50px.

I pretty much have no idea what I'm doing in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        dimen = $.extend($self.position(), {
             width:  $self.outerWidth(),
             height: $self.outerHeight()
        });

    if( e.which === 13 && $.trim(this.value).length ) {
        $('<div>', {
             text: this.value,
             css: {
                 position:   'absolute',
                 width:      dimen.width,
                 height:     dimen.height,
                 left:       dimen.left,
                 top:        dimen.top
             }
        }).appendTo($self.parent());

        $self.val('').css('position', 'absolute').animate({top: '+=50'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/81/

Comment: I drown when smothered by your absolute __pro-ness.__ Best solution yet, but a bit OTT with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

var content = $('#input_id'').val();
var elem = $('').addClass('class_name').html(content)

$('#id_of_element_to_append').append(elem)

Give the above a try.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this - ?

```
$('#myinput').css({top: $(this).offset().top+50}).prepend('<div><input type="text" value="'+$('#myinput').val()+'" /></div>').val('');
```

Sorry about the long chaining, I know there are other ways but this was the only way I could think of atm.

**EDIT:** this *may* work:

```
$('input').attr('value',$('#myinput').val()).prependTo($('#myinput'));
$('#myinput').css({top: $(this).offset().top+50}).val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following functions:

```
$("input#myinput").val() - gives you the value in the input field with id="myinput"
$("input#myinput").val("") - clears the input field with id="myinput"
$("div#mydiv").html("blah") - sets the content of the div with id="mydiv" to blah
$("div#mydiv").append("blah") - adds blah to the current content of the div with id="mydiv"
$("div#mydiv").css({ marginTop: '50px' }); - Sets the margin of the div with id="mydiv"
```

Combining all this into an event handler should do what you need